# Opinions on using a domain object for a single string

Tags: java, oop

I am looking for some opinions when it comes to a small design decision.

I looked for other similar questions but I couldn't find any.

So here's the situation, the database contains a table with names of cities. The application retrieves these names and uses them somewhere.

Normally when it comes to database objects I would (and I believe you should) create a domain object in which you store all the related variables.
Ex:

```
public class City {

    private String name;

    public City(String _name){
        this.name = _name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

But in this case, I think that this is unnecessarily complex since there is only a single string for each database object. So I saved the city name in a String. The main reason for this is because I think it uses less memory (although the difference is small (I think, I'm not an expert)), it also removes one class and a small number of lines from the codebase. And it saves me from typing said lines ;)

I would love to hear your thoughts on this, what you would personally do and what are potential advantages or disadvantages of both methods.

Comment: I generally don't like the idea because it won't scale well.  What I mean by this is that suppose you add another field to the table.  Well now you can't just use a collection of primitive strings, you would have to do a refactor.

Comment: Memory, amount of classes and lines of code are irrelevant. What matters is whether the City will ever become anything more complex than just a name. Maybe you'll want to know if it's the capital at one point, or store the population of the city.

Comment: I can totally see where the two of you are coming from, and I think that is completely dependent on the application that is being made. I think that in my original case this isn't really an issue but that is something that has to be decided for every case separately.

Comment: More importantly, **what** is a **City** in your domain? Is it an entity, is it a value? Cities are linked to what? What if the name of a city changes?

Comment: @plalx it is just a string in the database that gets retrieved, used (let's say for this example it just gets printed) and then the application finishes. If the city gets renamed, that would happen in the db and the actual application will not suffer from it (in my opinion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, it is better to use a domain object because it will give you more flexibility if you decide to add some more attributes. Let's say for example you pass this value to some methods in your code, next time you want to add some attribute to your city object it will be easier because all of the methods are already getting an object and not a single string.

Comment: Good point :) Like I said above, I think this is something that has to be viewed for every case since there are cases in which you are pretty damn certain (of course you can never be 100% sure but you can be pretty close) that there won't be any additional attributes without the purpose of the entire application changing.